# What's the difference between $@ and $*

Tags: bash, shell

According to [this page](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/%24IFS), $@ and $* do pretty much the same thing:

```
The $@ holds list of all arguments passed to the script. 
The $* holds list of all arguments passed to the script.
```

After searching all the top hits in google, I'm not able to find any explanation why there would be 2 seemingly duplicate syntaxes.

They appear to work the same in my scripts.

```
cat foo.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo The parameters passed in are $@
echo The parameters passed in are $*

./foo.sh herp derp
The parameters passed in are herp derp
The parameters passed in are herp derp
```

1. Is one preferred over the other?
2. Why are there 2 builtin variables to do the exact same thing?

---

Additional sources
[bash.cyberciti.biz](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Category%3aBash_Parameters)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between $\* and $@?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41571/what-is-the-difference-between-and). Also http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94126/should-i-use-or and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9590/in-bash-what-is-the-safest-way-to-pass-variables-to-another-program-or

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between $@ and $* in UNIX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307672/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-unix), [What is the difference between $@ and $* in shell scripts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2761723/what-is-the-difference-between-and-in-shell-scripts), [What the difference between “$@” and “$*” in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008695/what-the-difference-between-and-in-bash).

Comment: This does appear to be a duplicate. Strange that I couldn't find that other question when I searched for it.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

They aren't the same.  `$*` is a single string, whereas `$@` is an actual array.  To see the difference, execute the following script like so:

```
 > ./test.sh one two "three four"
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Using \"\$*\":"
for a in "$*"; do
    echo $a;
done

echo -e "\nUsing \$*:"
for a in $*; do
    echo $a;
done

echo -e "\nUsing \"\$@\":"
for a in "$@"; do
    echo $a;
done

echo -e "\nUsing \$@:"
for a in $@; do
    echo $a;
done
```

The explanation and the results for the four cases are below.

In the first case, the parameters are regarded as one long *quoted* string:

```
Using "$*":
one two three four
```

Case 2 (unquoted) - the string is broken into words by the `for` loop:

```
Using $*:
one
two
three
four
```

Case 3 - it treats each element of $@ as a quoted string:

```
Using "$@":
one
two
three four
```

Last case - it treats each element as an unquoted string, so the last one is again split by  what amounts to `for three four`:

```
Using $@:
one
two
three
four
```

Comment: Why make such subtle design?

Comment: I agree, it's a hacked, non-intuitive design predating Bash, the idea that "$@" should expand to multiple words. Some other syntax was needed. And that other syntax should have worked not only with $*, but also with $anyOtherVariable. Probably, unquoted $@ should have been words, and ${@otherVariable} should have worked similarly. Decades too late now!

Answer (score 26):

The difference comes in how they are expanded.

`$*` expands to a single argument with all the elements delimited by spaces (actually the first character of `$IFS`).
`$@` expands to multiple arguments.

For example

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "With *:"
for arg in "$*"; do echo "<$arg>"; done
echo
echo "With @:"
for arg in "$@"; do echo "<$arg>"; done
```

```
$ /tmp/test.sh 1  2 "3  4"
With *:
<1 2 3  4>

With @:
<1>
<2>
<3  4>
```

Comment: The OP want to know difference between `$*` and `$@`, not `"$*"` and `"$@"`.

Comment: `actually the first character of $IFS` i find that annotation really critical , as if you've recklessly defined IFS as a long string ,bash won't raise and error and would just use the first characters of the string (even if it was a space preceding the desired character)

Answer (score 12):

You can review [Bash Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) for more information.  These to do pretty much the same thing with the difference of how it's separated:

> `$*` - Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the IFS special variable.
>
> `$@` - Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, each parameter expands to a separate word.

But unless you set `IFS` to value other then default it could look identical.

Comment: This is the best explanation imo, because it notes that they are the same, and only behave differently when *quoted*.

Answer (score 6):

> Is one preferred over the other?

A short answer is `"$@"`.

If you use them without double quote, they are the same. There is no one preferred over the other in this case. But I suggest you to always use them with double quote, except you know what exactly you want.

> Why are there 2 builtin variables to do the exact same thing?

There are no difference between `$*` and `$@`, but `"$@"` and `"$*"` have.

You can see my answer in [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94126/should-i-use-or/94135#94135) to see how are they different.